# is it possible that SQL Profiler trace does not show calls done within a trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-server-profiler

I am just suspicious that the SQL Profiler does not show the calls done within by one of the triggers I have.

If I am right,

Is there a setting to force profiler to show also the calls done within triggers?

Note: The trigger I am talking about makes some sp calls

Comment: How are you defining a 'call' - the EXEC of a stored procedure or a bunch of SQL statements?

Comment: Which events are you profiling?  Do you have any filters enabled?

Comment: I am using the default settings of SqlProfiler. (Not familier with its settings to be honest)

Comment: @pencilCake - you should probably learn more about Profiler before asking questions that imply there's something wrong with it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the `SP:StmtCompleted` and/or `SP:Completed` events to your trace setup - this should provide you with what you're after.

Comment: mind the "SP" I got mistaken with the "RPC" thats not working for all queries

Answer (score 1):

Some possibilities include:

- Not choosing the correct EventClasses to monitor.
- Inadvertently filtering out what you wish to record.
- The specific step of interest within the Trigger is not being executed (conditional operations etc.)

If your Trigger is definitely executing T-SQL code then it will be recordable.

See [The Basics of SQL Server Profiler](http://sqlserverpedia.com/blog/sql-server-performance-tuning/the-basics-of-sql-server-profiler/) and for more generic Performance Tuning see [Performance Tuning for SQL Server](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/sql-server-performance-tuning/)